# How to use TestContainers to run embeddedmysql for junit?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I was using embedded mysql in my JUnit's following https://github.com/wix-incubator/wix-embedded-mysql.
but now they have removed support for latest mysql versions. So I wanted to shift to Test Containers as they have suggested, but I don't know how can I use it?
I am using EmbeddedMysqlConfig.class on the same basis as suggeted in the github site.My earlier config looked like :-

```
@Configuration
 @Profile({"mysql"})
 @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring", name = 
"datasource.jdbcUrl")
 public class EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig {

  protected static Logger logger = 
 LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmbeddedMySqlDbConfig.class);

  @Bean(name = "downloadConfig")
  DownloadConfig downloadConfig() {
    String downloadPath = "/app/mysql";
    logger.info("Embedded MySQL download path is {}", downloadPath);
    DownloadConfig config = 
 aDownloadConfig().withCacheDir(downloadPath).build();
    return config;
 }

 @Bean(name = "mysqldConfig")
 MysqldConfig mysqldConfig(@Value("${spring.datasource.username}") 
String 
 dbUsername,
        @Value("${spring.datasource.password}") String dbPassword, 
 @Value("${mysql.port}") int port) {
    MysqldConfig config = 
aMysqldConfig(v5_7_latest).withPort(port).withUser(dbUsername, 
dbPassword).build();
    return config;
 }

  private void addSchema(String databaseName, Builder builder) {
    SchemaConfig schema = aSchemaConfig(databaseName).build();
    builder.addSchema(schema);
  }

 @Bean(name = "embeddedMysql")
  EmbeddedMysql embeddedMysql(@Qualifier("downloadConfig") 
DownloadConfig 
 downloadConfig,
        @Qualifier("mysqldConfig") MysqldConfig config, 
 @Value("${mysql.databaseName}") String databaseName,
        @Value("${mysql.databaseName1}") String databaseName1) {
     try {
        Builder builder = new Builder(config, downloadConfig);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            String name = databaseName;
            if (i == 1) {
                name = null;
                if (databaseName1 != null && 
  databaseName1.trim().length() > 0) {
                    name = databaseName1;
                }
            }
            if (name != null) {
                addSchema(name, builder);
            }
         }
        EmbeddedMysql mysql = builder.start();
        logger.info("embedded mysql started");
        return mysql;
     } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
     }
 }

 @Bean(name = "dataSource")
 @DependsOn("embeddedMysql")
 public DataSource dataSource(@Value("${spring.datasource.username}") 
 String dbUsername,
        @Value("${spring.datasource.password}") String dbPassword,
        @Value("${spring.datasource.jdbcUrl}") String url,
        @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}") String 
 driverClassName) {

    DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder = 
 DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSourceBuilder.url(url);
    dataSourceBuilder.username(dbUsername);
    dataSourceBuilder.password(dbPassword);
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
 }

 @Bean(name = "requestDataSource")
 @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "request", name = 
"datasource.jdbcUrl")
 @DependsOn("dataSource")
 public DataSource 
 requestDataSource(@Value("${request.datasource.username}") String 
 dbUsername,
        @Value("${spring.datasource.password}") String dbPassword,
        @Value("${request.datasource.jdbcUrl}") String url,
        @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}") String 
driverClassName) {
    DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder = 
DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSourceBuilder.url(url);
    dataSourceBuilder.username(dbUsername);
    dataSourceBuilder.password(dbPassword);
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Please let me know how we can replace with TestContainers.

Comment: Don't. Just use MySQL, there is no need to use the embedded version if you are using Testcontainers. So just use the regular MySQL container from Testcontainers and totally ditch Embedded MySQL.

Comment: Do you have any good link that can help me do that and run MySQL container?

Comment: A good article from [atomicJar](https://www.atomicjar.com/2023/05/spring-boot-3-1-0-testcontainers-for-testing-and-local-development/) about  how to do it.

Comment: Well [the documentation](https://testcontainers.com/modules/mysql/) itself to start. And depending on which Spring Boot version you can leverage the Spring Boot Testcontainers support.